# How to generate form fields based on specific table columns fields names only?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I'm generating dynamic form inputs based on table column field names with this simple code :

```
<form id="generate-user-register-form" type="POST">
                <?php 
                $queryuser= "DESCRIBE users";
                $resultstmt_queryuser= $conn->query($queryuser); 

                $fields = array();

                while($row = $resultstmt_queryuser->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $fields[] = $row['Field'];
                }

                foreach($fields as $field): ?>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php echo "$field: "; ?>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="<?php echo $field; ?>" />
                   </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit"/>
            </form>
```

Ok this works great but the first 10 fields are unnecessary and the first column `id` is autoincrement so it is definitely not needed as a form input. Is there a way for me to only generate specific fields without having to manually hard code something like the below code 10 times?

```
 if($field !="id"){
//generate input
}
```

Comment: how do you know which column names to use? how about another table listing the ones that should be form fields and query that?

Comment: Instead of `foreach` use a `for` loop and start the counter at 10?  If you're building an isolated system, just build the form the way it's supposed to look and make the inputs you want to make.  If you're building a framework, maybe keep system fields and user-maintainable fields in separate related tables?

Comment: you can use a counter in a `foreach()` its not a very robust solution, what if yoiu have to add or remove from the table, or change the positions in the form ..

Comment: @IdontDownVote: I'll take this as an answer yes. Works. I must be too fried for not having even thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do might have different approaches considering how to decide if a field should be an input or not. For example.

Consider that your table would look like this:

```
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| id | name_input | email_input | phone_input | created_at |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| 1  | John Smith | not@me.com  | 888 333 444 | 2018-08-26 |
| 2  | Lila White | not@us.com  | 412 322 555 | 2018-08-27 |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

So, with this table you could easily find the keyword **input** in the columns and assign only them to the form:

```
while($row = $resultstmt_queryuser->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (strpos($row['Field'], '_input') === false) {
        continue;
    }
    $fields[] = $row['Field'];
}
```

Or, as @IdontDownVote pointed out in the comments above, you can use a count inside the loop and only add the fields if after some number or betweem some, or before another, like:

```
$count = 0;
while($row = $resultstmt_queryuser->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($count < 1 /* adding extra clauses here as && $count > 5 */) {
        continue;
    }
    $fields[] = $row['Field'];
}someone
```

But I would advise against it. **Why?** you might ask.

Well, by nature, each field is different. The machine will certainly not know what is the label for a specific field, or what validation it should have, or what kind of information it should hold.

Most commonly, *ids* are integers, thought they might not be. But what about `date` fields? Or phone numbers? Or Postal Codes?

Generating dynamic inputs for each of them you might also have to read the name of the column as the label of each field, but still, some information you are bound to **hardcoded** at some point.

Validations of phone numbers, validations of postal codes, emails, websites.

Most of it will have to be hardcoded anyway in the backend before this information reach the database. So, if you are gonna have to write some specific rules for specific fields, why not specify this fields in the form as well?

It makes your life easier when trying to track down each field and you won't be entirely dependent on creating **ignore rules** for certain fields to be displayed like: `created_at`, `created_by`. When these fields are commonly updated by the system and not by the user (knowing who did what and when, of course).

But well, TL; DR; sometimes hardcoding is clearer and faster (on the long run) than the opposite.

**[Edit]**

Adding the count to the answer to be visible, if @IdontDownVote post this answer, please choose his answer.

Comment: This answer uses the hardcoded 'if's the OP is trying to avoid, only in a different part of the code.